# SortBy from p:dataTable not working with dataModel

Tags: primefaces, primefaces-datatable

Im trying to implement a sort by in a column inside a p:dataTable, i use a dataModel to get the data to the table, if i use a arrayList to get the data the sort by works, theres a way to make the sort by work with a dataModel?

The error i get when using dataModel:

Error Rendering View[/private/tarefas/tarefaListagem.xhtml]

java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: null
at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableList.sort(Collections.java:1333) ~[na:1.8.0_265]
at java.util.Collections.sort(Collections.java:177) ~[na:1.8.0_265]

Comment: Hi, please start by reading [ask] and [mcve] and  version info

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the unmodifiable list.

Do it new ArrayList().addAll(unmodifiable list)